# Unable to assign default values to arguments in Python argparse

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I am using Python `argparse` to take in parameters through the CLI. I have tried using the following but when I don't give any one of the arguments, it gives the output as `None`. I want then default ones to be the ones provided in `const=`. Please take a look.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--input', nargs='?', const='testInput')
parser.add_argument('--target', nargs='?', const='testTarget')
parser.add_argument('--msg', nargs='?', const='helloFromTheOtherSide')
args = parser.parse_args()
print args.input
```

If I don't give input, it prints it as `None` as I said. I want it to print `TestInput` instead..

Answer (score 1):

Use the `default` argument:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--input', nargs='?', default='testInput')
parser.add_argument('--target', nargs='?', default='testTarget')
parser.add_argument('--msg', nargs='?', default='helloFromTheOtherSide')
args = parser.parse_args()
print args.input
```

Answer (score 0):

With

```
parser.add_argument('--input', nargs='?', default='testInput', const='aConst')
```

you have a 3 way choice

```
prog                  # input='testInput'
prog --input          # input='aConst'
prog --input myfile   # input='myfile'
```

If you don't need that `aConst` option, omit the `nargs='?'`.  Since it is a flagged argument it is already optional.  It doesn't need the `?'.

```
parser.add_argument('--input', default='testInput')
```